# Efficient way to extract a sub-array in numpy based on the value of one column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Short version:
I'm looking for an efficient way of doing exactly this :

```
my_data = big_data[big_data[:, 1] == p_num, 2:]
```

Long version:
I'm processing very big files.
First I read one of them into a numpy array "data"
Then I want to use multiprocessing and, in order to avoid to much exchanges,
I use a multiprocessing.Array :

```
data_shared = Array(ctypes.c_double, data.size)
big_data = np.frombuffer(data_shared.get_obj())
big_data = data
```

Later, I have a function that all process execute to extract data of interest :

```
def extract(p_num):
    global big_data

    my_data = big_data[big_data[:, 1] == p_num, 2:]
    return my_data
```

After that I do a lot of computation on my_data, part of them in fortran with f2py, so I thing I really need to extract those data, and can't play with a mask or something like that.

Problem is that this extract function is very long.

I tried to use f2py or cython without success, so I'm asking you.

Answer (score 0):

When working with very large datasets in Python, I have resorted to using HDF5 (e.g. h5py or pytables) in combination with numpy/scipy.  Hence, I suggest the following approach.

- Store the data in HDF5 format, then loading them will probably be faster, and you can **slice the data while loading them**.  Be careful of how to structure the HDF5 file, as this can impact the performance (especially if it is compressed).
- After loading the data, be careful to vectorize things in numpy/scipy, as vectorized functions are usually very efficient.  (But you probably already knew this.)
- If you're performing lots of linear algebra, then switching to more efficient BLAS/LAPACK implementations in numpy/scipy can help (e.g. MKL).

Finally, if the code is still to computationally inefficient, you probably need to redesign things -- or switch to C or other efficient compiled languages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right now, I have no control on how the data is produced, so HDF5 is a no go (but I use it time to time). The point of my function is to extract the data in order to use vectorized functions, that's why I didn't want to play with masks. The computational part is done in fortran with f2py, and is very efficient since we do simple things (but a lot of them).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem by reordering my big array in fortran.
So now I :

- read the file
- count the number of p_num in the big array (in fortran, but not sure it's important)
- reorder my array adding a dimension given by the p_num (in fortran)

This solution is much much more efficient in my case.